# Libray wrapped React component, how to find DOM children with Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a library wrapper component, which generates it's own markup rendered in `componentDidMount`. Given the following...

```
// <MyComponent />

componentDidMount() {
  transform(this.ref);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className='foo' ref={(self) => this.ref = self} />
  )
}
```

where (external lib) `transform` does *something* to alter the rendered markup. Assume this to be transformed to the following...

```
<div class="foo">
  <article>
    <h2>noms</h2>
    <section>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>pizza</li>
        <li>taco</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

How do I actually use the Enzyme API on the rendered markup?

---

I am trying to [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) the component, then to [`find`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) my `.list` element, but the result is never actually found with a length of `0`. What is wrong with my following test?

```
let wrapper = Enzyme.mount(<MyComponent />);

let list = wrapper.find('.list'); // nope
```

I believe my basic setup to be correct, as calling `wrapper.html()` *does* actually return the above transformed markup in full. What am I missing here?

Comment: you should add this line of code and see what it prints out. this will give you an idea of what Enzyme is rendering

`wrapper.tap(n => console.log(n.debug()))`

Comment: It's only rendering the first child, but `.html()` returns the entire tree. Why is it only one level deep, and, how can I go deeper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `wrapper` is your component, and  `ref` is a property of your component that points to the DIV, this should work:

```
let wrapper = Enzyme.mount(<MyComponent />);

let list = wrapper.instance().ref;
```

Comment: This is returning `[Function: ref]`. I tried calling wrapper.ref.find('.list'), and an exception is thrown. I am not sure what I should be seeing here. Thoughts?

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by calling `wrapper.instance().ref`. If you edit your answer I'll gladly accept in case others may find this helpful in the future

Comment: Fixed now. Good one @scniro !